# Windows 10 - Name & Timeout of Sign-out Screen

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

I want to set the display timeout (turn off monitor) for the Sign-Out screen on Windows 10.

I have Windows 10 with 4 user accounts (3 other than I).

The sign-out screen is the screen that appears after a User clicks on the "sign out" option.

I have searched the internet and found that the **Lock** screen timeout can be set.  Also, the Lock screen is User dependent.  I didn't find any timeout settings for the "sign out" screen.

I set the Lock screen timeout to 1 minute and that didn't have any affect for Sign-out when another User signed out.

I don't want to keep having to press the power button on my monitor every time somebody signs out.

**Edit 1: Screen snapshot**
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of this "sign out" screen might be helpful;.  There is no official screen called that.

Comment: @Ramhound:  See Edit 1, I uploaded the screen snapshot.